# Crear un Package on Swift

Tags: swift

Estoy tratando de crear un Package e incluirlo en una App. He simplificado todo lo posible tanto el programa como el Package.

Los códigos son:

Prueba251_uso_packageApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import PckNorma

@main
struct Prueba251_uso_packageApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(n: Norma())
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import PckNorma

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var n: Norma = Norma()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text(n.norma())
        }
        .padding(100)
    }
}
```

El Package:

Norma:

```
import Foundation

public class Norma {
    
    public init() {}
    
    public func norma() -> String {
        return "200"
    }
}
```

El Navegador del proyecto:

[image: El Navegador del proyecto:]

Cuando compilo obtengo los siguientes errores:
Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code a (use -v to see invocation)

Respecto del primer error en el "report" aparece:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  PckNorma.Norma.__allocating_init() -> PckNorma.Norma, referenced from:
      variable initialization expression of Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView.n : PckNorma.Norma in ContentView.o
      Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView.init() -> Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView in ContentView.o
      default argument 0 of Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView.init(n: PckNorma.Norma) -> Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView in ContentView.o
      closure #1 () -> Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView in Prueba251_uso_package.Prueba251_uso_packageApp.body.getter : some in Prueba251_uso_packageApp.o
  type metadata accessor for PckNorma.Norma, referenced from:
      variable initialization expression of Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView.n : PckNorma.Norma in ContentView.o
      Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView.init() -> Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView in ContentView.o
      default argument 0 of Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView.init(n: PckNorma.Norma) -> Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView in ContentView.o
      closure #1 () -> Prueba251_uso_package.ContentView in Prueba251_uso_package.Prueba251_uso_packageApp.body.getter : some in Prueba251_uso_packageApp.o
  nominal type descriptor for PckNorma.Norma, referenced from:
      _symbolic _____ 8PckNorma0B0C in ContentView.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

debe ser un error "tonto" pero me está volviendo loco.

Saludos de Víctor.-

Comment: Que tienes en ese `main` file, trata removerlo pueda ser que este creando conflictos